# Remote usb connection C

Tags: c, windows, connection, usb

I'm trying to connect to an USB device that's on a remote PC (because there is no 64-bit driver for it, remote PC is 32-bit).

I know the commands that I need to send to make settings on the device but I don't know how I can get connected to it. Is there a C++ or C# library that makes it possible to connect to this device on a remote PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to build something using Microsoft's [RemoteFX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817581%28WS.10%29.aspx) technology, assuming Windows is your target platform.